Azure Image Builder (AIB): 'sudo apt update -y' fails with 'ERROR: Bad port'
Executing sudo apt update -y as part of a shell script from a Customizer "Shell" action fails with the following error message (packer logs):
ui:     azure-arm: + sudo apt update -y
ui:     azure-arm: Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
... (truncated)
ui:     azure-arm: 7Progress: [ 98%] [########################################################..] 87Progress: [ 99%] [#########################################################.] rocessing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.57) ...
ui:     azure-arm: Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
ui:     azure-arm: Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
ui:     azure-arm: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ui:     azure-arm: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...
ui:     azure-arm:
ui:     azure-arm: '
ui:     azure-arm: ERROR: Bad port

But when I execute the same command as an inline script it succeeds:
...
    customize: [
      {
        name: 'Update System'
        type: 'Shell'
        inline: [
          'sudo apt update -y'
          'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt install -y --no-install-recommends nginx'
          'sudo ufw allow "Nginx HTTP"'
        ]
      }
    ]
...


Here are the Detailed Scripts
install.sh:
#!/bin/bash
set -x;

sudo apt update -y
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt install -y --no-install-recommends nginx
sudo ufw allow "Nginx HTTP"

.bicep template:
param ImageVersion string // = '0.0.4'
param WorkspaceUri string // = 'https://bart.blob.core.windows.net/workspaces/fantastic.tar.gz'

... (truncated)

resource imageTemplate 'Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates@2022-02-14' = {
  location: resourceGroup().location
  name: 'fantastic-image-template-${replace(ImageVersion, '.', '-')}'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', managedIdentity.name)}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    vmProfile: {
      vmSize: 'Standard_D4_v3'
      osDiskSizeGB: 30
    }
    source: {
      type: 'PlatformImage'
      publisher: 'Canonical'
      offer: 'UbuntuServer'
      sku: '18.04-LTS'
      version: 'latest'
    }
    customize: [
    { 
      type: 'File' 
      name: 'download bundle'
      sourceUri: WorkspaceUri
      destination: '/tmp/fantastic.tar.gz'
    }
    {
      name: 'unpack bundle'
      type: 'Shell'
      inline: [
        'mkdir -p /home/azureuser/fantastic'
        'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi'
        'tar -xvf /tmp/fantastic.tar.gz -C /home/azureuser/fantastic/'
        'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi'
        'chmod +x /home/azureuser/fantastic/*.sh'
        'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi'
      ]
    }
    {
      name: 'execute scripts'
      type: 'Shell'
      inline: [
        '/home/azureuser/fantastic/install.sh'
        'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi'
        'rm -rf /home/azureuser/fantastic' // cleanup
      ]
    }
    ]
    distribute: [
      {
        type: 'VHD'
        runOutputName: 'fantastic-vhd-${replace(ImageVersion, '.', '-')}'
      }
    ]
  }
}

